# How to get new value of element in asp.net on case user change it

Tags: html, asp.net, element

I using a drag list as code provided and user could to drag it and provide new list, how can I get new value of this list.
I tried these code but, always it's gives me old data.

```
string strSort= lblSort.Text;

string strSortable = sortable.InnerHtml;
```

Also I tried to check these elements during PostBack, again I can't get new value of this list.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet"href="https://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/style.css">
  <style>
  #sortable { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 60%; }
  #sortable li { margin: 0 3px 3px 3px; padding: 0.4em; padding-left: 1.5em; font-size: 1.4em; height: 18px; }
  #sortable li span { position: absolute; margin-left: -1.3em; }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#sortable" ).sortable();
    $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>

   <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:Label ID="lblSort" runat="server" >
     <ul id="sortable" runat="server">
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 1</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 2</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 3</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s">
</ul>
</asp:Label>
 </form>

</body>
</html>
```